# Switching from a Spritekit Scene back to the storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Simply put, I want to go from a spritekit Scene to a view in the Main Storyboard.  It's easy to go from the main storyboard to a spritekit scene in swift.  But I can't figure out how to go back to the storyboard.  Thanks for the help.  Cheers.

Comment: Post your code and your storyboard for clarity of what you want done.  You never techically go from a storyboard to a scene, the scene sits inside of a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial viewController: an empty viewController with a button to present the GameViewController

GameViewController: the typical GameViewController of the "Hello World" Sprite-kit template. (This is a simplified version of the two scripts as of course you will have more code in yours, however, for the purpose of sharing what I did, this is easier)

My Goal: I wanted to present the first viewController from my SKScene game with the correct deallocation of my scene.

Description: To obtain the result I've extended the SKSceneDelegate class to build a custom protocol/delegate that make the transition from the GameViewController to the first initial controller (main menu). This method could be extended to other viewControllers of your game.  This delegate is made use of in the return to main menu function.  Make sure to put this function before you call the class for your spritekit script.

The two scripts are shown below.  Hope this helps anybody else who had my question.

UIViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
class GameViewController: UIViewController,TransitionDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                scene.delegate = self as TransitionDelegate
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
func returnToMainMenu(){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    guard  let storyboard = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard else { return }
    if let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() {
        print("go to main menu")
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

Game Script:

```
import SpriteKit
protocol TransitionDelegate: SKSceneDelegate {
    func returnToMainMenu()
}
class GameScene: SKScene {
   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2),completion:{[unowned self] in
            guard let delegate = self.delegate else { return }
            self.view?.presentScene(nil)
            (delegate as! TransitionDelegate).returnToMainMenu()
        })
    }
     deinit {
        print("\n THE SCENE \((type(of: self))) WAS REMOVED FROM MEMORY (DEINIT) \n")
    }
}
```